# Make children wrap inside a div with a certain height

Tags: html, css

If I have a set of children elements in a parent element, and the parent is set to a certain height that's less than all of the list items added up, by default it appears the children just flow straight out of the parent:

http://jsfiddle.net/BxJLH/

```
<ul>
    <li><a href = '#'> Item </a></li>
    <li><a href = '#'> Item </a></li>
    <li><a href = '#'> Item </a></li>
    <li><a href = '#'> Item </a></li>
    <li><a href = '#'> Item </a></li>
    <li><a href = '#'> Item </a></li>
    <li><a href = '#'> Item </a></li>
    <li><a href = '#'> Item </a></li>
    <li><a href = '#'> Item </a></li>
    <li><a href = '#'> Item </a></li>
</ul>
```

But is it possible to make it so the children **wrap** and all stay inside the parent? Using the jsfiddle as the example, could we create two 'columns' of list items, with 7 `li`s in the first 'column', and `3` in the second?

*update*

I want the div to stay 142px heigh, and the children to form 2 columns inside it. [I'm trying to create a menu as seen here](http://ddthemesdemo.com/biosphere/), and I just think it would be cool to be able to loop the li's from the database in one fell swoop.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible with just CSS, you can with Javascript fairly easily, but If you are only looking for CSS, I would suggest making each `li` 50% width and floating them left so they always show in 2 columns.

Comment: Starkers, Here's a VERY QUICK prototype using javascript (jQuery) http://jsfiddle.net/BxJLH/3/ I've made two unordered lists (you can make them side by side using CSS) and you can see if the height of the LIs exceed the height of the UL, it will place that LI into the next list.  -- The only reason I gave class names to the lists is because jsfiddle doesn't like it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/BxJLH/7/)

I used

```
.unordered-list {
    -moz-columns: 2 142px;
    -webkit-columns: 2 142px;
    columns: 2 142px;
}
```

EDIT:

Look at this [JSFiddleUpdated](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/BxJLH/12/)
The only problem is, the CSS of UL may not apply for the li items in 2nd column.

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: It seems this is also not what he's looking for - he wants the list items to go to the bottom of the div, then go to a new column if there are more than can handle.  Not to evenly place side to side.