# How to make a multi-column layout with undefined height that flows from one column to the next?

Tags: html, css

I have a single column layout with an arbitrary number of lists, each having an arbitray number of list items. At a certain breakpoint I want that layout to become two columns, but without telling any of those lists what column to go to - it should just flow. A third breakpoint will then split the layout into three columns.

Requirements:

- The same, unaltered markup needs to work across breakpoints
- No javascript
- No fixed height for lists
- No fixed height for the parent container that holds the lists
- No differentiating lists from one another via any kind of selector

Things I tried:

- Flexbox - got the closest with this, but it requires a fixed height parent container to push lists to the second and third columns, otherwise they flow down endlessly in the first column.
- Grid layout - requires various selectors to instruct items as to which column they should go in.

Other solutions break the requirements. I haven't added code because the code literally consists of a series of anonymous, unordered lists.

Here's what I have with Flexbox: http://jsbin.com/mabigisu/1/edit

Uncommenting the height shows that it works with fixed height, which I can't have, and there's no way to limit the number of columns.

Comment: since you don't have a start at your code to actually do what you want to do, start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262555/make-children-wrap-inside-a-div-with-a-certain-height

Comment: @ntgCleaner There's no start because every direction I'm aware of leads to a dead end. The question you linked to is specifically about a fixed height scenario, and isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I must've read too quickly.  What controls the breakpoints? I guess I am confused as to what the request is.  If the breakpoint is controlled by browser width, you can use CSS3's media queries and then use `:nth-of-type(3n+3)` or something similar

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the response. I didn't go into detail because my scenario is very basic. Breakpoints are controlled via media queries.

Comment: I just edited my last response which may help with what you're looking for http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: You can use my previous example with CSS3 Column count http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm aware of nth-child, but it's still a static mechanism. It can't discern how long each list is, so one column could easily end up much longer or shorter than the others. This is probably the best bet so far, but hoping for a way to achieve true flow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49511/discussion-between-shawn-erquhart-and-ntgcleaner)

Comment: Sorry I missed that chat Shawn,  The column layout should make it so they are evenly placed.  It takes every nth (second or third) list element and places it in a specific column, so it should always be even lists save the 1 or 2 leftovers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does this suit?

Its based heavily on [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout) Pinterest like solution from Kushagra Agarwal. The down side is that it does require a wrapping div (.wrapper) as well as the parent

The CSS.....

```
.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.parent {
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-gap: 15px;
    column-fill: auto;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width:100%;
    margin:5px;
}
ul li, h5 {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
@media (min-width: 420px) {
    .parent {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .parent {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    .parent {
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    .parent {
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}
```

Here's a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KqygU/1/

Comment: Multi-column!  This is most definitely the solution I was looking for, the whole multi column thing fell completely off my radar.  Thanks a million.

Comment: No worries, I only realised as I'd bee looking at a similar thing for a potential upcoming project and it struck me your problem was quite similar